# After filling first card number field I can't find any iframes on the page. How to solve this

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver, webdriverwait

class TestAplazame(unittest.TestCase):

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls, headless=False) -> None:
    cls.chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    if headless:
        cls.chrome_options.headless = True
    else:
        cls.chrome_options.headless = False

    cls.chrome_options.add_argument(
        "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 10.0; Android 4.2.1; Microsoft; Lumia 640 XL LTE) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10166")
    cls.chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    cls.chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    cls.chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches',
                                               ['enable-automation'])
    cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"driver/chromedriver.exe", options=cls.chrome_options)
    cls.driver.maximize_window()  # maximize window if headless is not running
    cls.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    cls.wait = WebDriverWait(cls.driver, 20)

def test_checkout(self):
    self.driver.get("https://cdn.aplazame.com/widgets/demo/")
    self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "pay-with-aplazame"))).click()
    self.wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "aplazame-checkout-iframe")))
    self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "accepts_gdpr"))).click()
    self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "btn"))).click()
    time.sleep(3)
    self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "btn"))).click()
    self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "document_id"))).send_keys("X0345345 T")
    self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "birthday"))).send_keys("22121995")
    time.sleep(0.2)

    self.driver.find_element_by_name("job_status").click()  # profession selector
    self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "apz_typeahead__prediction_content"))).click()
    time.sleep(0.5)

    job = self.driver.find_element_by_name("job_sector")
    job.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
    job.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    nation = self.driver.find_element_by_name("nationality")
    nation.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
    nation.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    self.driver.find_element_by_name("checkout_checkboxes[aplazame_conditions]").click()  # checkbox check
    time.sleep(0.2)
    self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "btn"))).click()
```

`Look from here`

```
    iframes = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@name,'__privateStripeFrame')]")

    self.driver.switch_to.frame(iframes[0])
    self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "cardnumber")))
    card_number = self.driver.find_element_by_name("cardnumber")
    card_number.send_keys("4074655237184431")
```

`iframes are only available to the top block`
 `iframes elements are not available to the bottom block. included error message at the bottom`

```
    self.driver.switch_to.frame(iframes[1])  # frame switch to exp date
    self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "exp-date")))
    exp_field = self.driver.find_element_by_name("exp-date")
    exp_field.send_keys(1023)

    self.driver.switch_to.frame(iframes[2])
    self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "cvc")))
    exp_field = self.driver.find_element_by_name("cvc")
    exp_field.send_keys(657)

@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls) -> None:
    cls.driver.close()
    cls.driver.quit()
```

if **name** == '**main**':
unittest.main()

Even I can't find the same iframe anymore. What is the problem. how to fix it. It's a payment gateway test. gateway is from stripe I believe.
Here is the error message:

selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

When I am accessing the iframes variable after filling the card field instead of switching to the next iframe "StaleElementReferenceException" this exception is throwing.

Any help would be appreciated.

all three card fields are different iframes:
[image]

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do? Why you want other iframes?

Comment: In the credit card field. cardnumber, exp-date field, cvv all are different iframes. If I fill card number field and then try to switch to another iframe for (in code iframe2 variable) exp-date then I notice all the iframes gone from page not even the cardnumbers frame is there. If you need more information please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seems you are still in the earlier `iframe` you need to switch to `default_content()` before move to another `iframe.`

```
self.driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Then switch to another frame.

```
self.wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[name*='privateStripeFrame']")))
self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "exp-date")))
exp_field = self.driver.find_element_by_name("exp-date")
exp_field.send_keys(1023)
```

Let me know how this goes.

Comment: After filling cardnumber field I tried this but the list prints empty

self.driver.switch_to.default_content()
        iframes = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@name,'__privateStripeFrame')]")

Answer (score 0):

Please find the working code - For Expirary date you can continue that will card number itself and for cvc you have to find that element and fill it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get('https://stripe-payments-demo.appspot.com/')

CardFrame = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//iframe[contains(@name,\"privateStripeFrame\") and @title=\"Secure card payment input frame\"]")
driver.switch_to.frame(CardFrame)

CardNumber = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name=\"cardnumber\"]")))
CardNumber.send_keys("40746552371844310122")

CVC = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name=\"cvc\"]")))
CVC.send_keys("222")
```

Please mark it as answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Please look at the code. I've updated it. if it still goes with your reply please tell me.

Comment: Have you tried my code, what error it is showing?

Comment: Edit: selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document. 

I've updated the code at the top. please check.

Comment: Tried completely replacing my code with your code. Here is the error: 

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//iframe[contains(@name,"privateStripeFrame") and